# 調用transferFrom的函數時出現錯誤顯示Reason provided by the contract: "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin, transferfrom

What's the problem?

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Initializable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
contract Test {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    IERC20 public toke;
    function f(IERC20 _token)public{
        toke=_token;
    }

    function y(address u,uint256 i)public{
        toke.approve(msg.sender,i);
        toke.transferFrom(msg.sender,u,i);
        
    }
    
}
```

> transact to GLDToken.transferFrom errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason provided by the contract: "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance". Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: Can you write the title in English and format the code to look like code?

Answer (score 0):

With `toke.approve(msg.sender, i)`, you are approving `msg.sender` to transfer tokens from your contract.

With `toke.transferFrom(msg.sender, u, i)`, you are attempting to transfer tokens from `msg.sender`.

Bottom line, you should execute `approve(yourContractAddress, i)` using the `msg.sender` account.

Side note: you wouldn't want your code to work, because if it did, then it would mean that anyone could transfer tokens from anyone else, and the entire system would be worthless as a financial model.